# DStream does save empty file in Spark Streaming using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

Pardon if this question has been asked already. I am trying to save streamed data into HDFS using pyspark.
Files are being created successfully on HDFS but these files are empty. Below is the simple code I am using.

Please help on fixing this issue.

`from pyspark import SparkContext`

```
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

# Create a local StreamingContextwith two working thread and batch interval of 1 second
sc= SparkContext("local[2]", "NetworkWordCount")
ssc= StreamingContext(sc, 2)
```

`# Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:9999`

```
linesDStream= ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)

# Split each line into words
wordsDStream= linesDStream.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))

    # Count each word in each batch
pairsDStream= wordsDStream.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
wordCountsDStream= pairsDStream.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

`# save the content into HDFS`

```
wordCountsDStream.saveAsTextFiles("/home/cloudera/stream_Output/file")
wordCountsDStream.pprint()

# Start the computation

ssc.start() 
# Wait for the computation to terminate
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Using Cloudera quick start VM which comes with a spark 1.6.2 version.

Comment: Please can experts comment on my query

Comment: No one to my help?